How to calculate the trace of this matrix?
How do we calculate the trace of $(\mathbb{I}-X(X^\prime X)^{-1}X^\prime)\mathbb{J}_n$? This question stemmed from the below problem I came across:
Suppose we have the linear regression model: $y_i=x_i^{\prime} \beta+\epsilon_i, i=1,2, \ldots, n$, where $\mathbb{E}\left(\epsilon_i\right)=$ $0, \operatorname{Var}\left(\epsilon_i\right)=\sigma^2, i=1, \ldots, n$, and $\operatorname{Cov}\left(\epsilon_i, \epsilon_j\right)=\rho, 1 \leq i \neq j \leq n$. Assuming the covariance $\rho$ is known, derive an unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$ based on the data $\left\{\left(x_i, y_i\right)\right\}_{i=1}^n$.
I am trying to work out the expectation of the SSE as my first step.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(SSE) &= \mathbb{E} tr((\mathbb{I}-X(X^\prime X)^{-1}X^\prime)YY^\prime) \\
&= \mathbb{E} tr((\mathbb{I}-X(X^\prime X)^{-1}X^\prime)\epsilon \epsilon^\prime) \\
&=  tr \left((\mathbb{I}-X(X^\prime X)^{-1}X^\prime) (\mathbb{I}_n (\sigma^2-\rho)+\mathbb{J}_n \rho)\right) \\
&=(\sigma^2-\rho)(n-p)+\rho\cdot tr\left((\mathbb{I}-X(X^\prime X)^{-1}X^\prime)\mathbb{J}_n\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
And this is where I got stucked. I can choose to solve for $\sigma^2$ at this point, but it seems possible that the trace part can be further simplified. Any ideas or hints are appreciated!
(Also, we can safely assume that $X$ has a full column rank of $p$. )

What is $\mathbb{J}_n$ ?

@温泽海 It is a matrix of ones. This denotes the covariance structure of the random effects.

Are the error covariances just $\rho$ or $\rho\sigma^2$?

@StubbornAtom It's just $\rho$ for off-diagonal elements. It's $\sigma^2$ for diagonal elements.

Only simplification I can think of now is if there is an intercept in the model, in which case the trace part is exactly zero.

@StubbornAtom Yeah, I think you're probably right. I'll just write the answer this way. Certainly looks ugly though.
